# Nginx won't start -- .sock file not found/no such directory

Tags: nginx, django, socket

[image: /Users/peterkaminski/Downloads/Screen Shot 2016-07-21 at 3.58.46 PM.JPEG]

I'm trying to run my django application using uwsgi and nginx. It's been working for the past month, but today I edited file in the /sites-enabled/ dir and now nginx won't start.

Here are the error logs from nginx

[image]

### Update

Was able to get nginx running again by removing the .sock file from my /sites-enabled directory. Still would like to know what this error message means--a google search of the answer turns up nothing of usefulness.

Comment: Post your nginx.conf and confguration file for that site. It's giving you fairly clear error messages though, have you tried looking where the error messages said to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering your updated question, about why this caused a problem. Without seeing your configuration files this is mostly a guess. I think your nginx.conf has a line something like this in it

```
include /etc/nginx/enabled-sites/*;
```

In that directory referenced you probably had the studentprogress.sock file. Nginx picked up the file and tried to interpret it as configuration. As it wasn't a valid Nginx configuration file it caused an error.

Comment: Ah that makes sense now. That is indeed what my config file looks like. Not sure why the file gives that error, even though it works for uWSGI

Comment: Since you didn't post the contents of any of your files it's very difficult to answer that question. Please accept this answer if it helped solve your question.